# SQL Server Functions and Procedures

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying implement "Custom Auto Increment Values". The below code is MySQL the same I wanted in SQL Server. How to convert it to SQL Server?

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getNextCustomSeq;

CREATE FUNCTION getNextCustomSeq
(
    sSeqName VARCHAR(50),
    sSeqGroup VARCHAR(10)
) RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
BEGIN
    DECLARE nLast_val INT; 

    SET nLast_val =  (SELECT seq_val
                      FROM   _sequence
                      WHERE  seq_name = sSeqName
                      AND    seq_group = sSeqGroup);

    IF nLast_val IS NULL THEN
        SET nLast_val = 1;
        INSERT INTO _sequence (seq_name,seq_group,seq_val)
        VALUES (sSeqName,sSeqGroup,nLast_Val);
    ELSE
        SET nLast_val = nLast_val + 1;
        UPDATE _sequence SET seq_val = nLast_val
        WHERE seq_name = sSeqName AND seq_group = sSeqGroup;
    END IF; 
 
    SET @ret = (SELECT concat(sSeqGroup,'-',lpad(nLast_val,6,'0')));
    RETURN @ret;
END
```

Comment: Have a look at [SEQUENCES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx) on MS-Sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The T-SQL equivalent would be:

```sql
IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.getNextCustomSeq', N'FN') IS NOT NULL  
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.getNextCustomSeq;  

CREATE FUNCTION getNextCustomSeq(@sSeqName VARCHAR(50), @sSeqGroup VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @nLast_val INT;
    SELECT  @nLast_val = MAX(seq_val)
    FROM    _sequence
    WHERE   seq_name = sSeqName
        AND seq_group = sSeqGroup;

    IF @nLast_val IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @nLast_val = 1;
        INSERT INTO _sequence(seq_name, seq_group, seq_val)
        VALUES (@sSeqName, @sSeqGroup, @nLast_Val);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @nLast_val = @nLast_val + 1;
        UPDATE  _sequence
        SET seq_val = nLast_val
        WHERE   seq_name = @sSeqName
            AND seq_group = @sSeqGroup;
    END; 

    DECLARE @ret VARCHAR(20);
    SELECT @ret = @sSeqGroup + '-' + right(replicate('0', 6) + @nLast_val, 6)
    RETURN(@ret);
END
```